# Telnet works for localhost however not for the raw IP address

Tags: java, networking, telnet, telnetlib

I'm running a socket on my Mac laptop and when I telnet the IP address of my computer it  says (IP is hidden for security reasons):

```
telnet 7-.---.--.--- 4005  
Trying 7-.---.--.---...  
telnet: connect to address 7-.---.--.---: Connection refused  
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

However when I do telnet on "localhost" it works it says (did not hide any info this is the raw message):

```
Trying ::1...  
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused  
Trying fe80::1...  
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused  
Trying 127.0.0.1...  
Connected to localhost.
```

**Update - Opened Firewall**

Now after opening all of the ports localhost still works the same way as before however when I try the raw IP I get this new error:

```
Trying 7-.---.--.---...  
telnet: connect to address 7-.---.--.---: Operation timed out  
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: program only listening on loopback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a firewall: generally localhost is not barred, but the external IP interface is.

Answer (score 1):

The server is listening on the loopback interface only (`INADDR_LOOPBACK`), not all interfaces (`INADDR_ANY`) or a firewall is interfering with the connection.

Comment: How should I fix this problem?  I opened the ports on my router however it still doesn't work.

Comment: If the server is listening on the loopback interface only there should be a command line option or configuration option to change that.